# Parsing returns from AltLabel in a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata, skos

In a Wikidata SPARQL query such as the following, I want to be able to use a custom delimiter for the returns for `?placeOfBirthAltLabel`.

The problem is that some values under `?placeOfBirthAltLabel` contain commas

e.g. 
synonyms for "New York" include "New York, USA" as a single entry.

However, as the returns are comma delimited, this single entry will be parsed as two separate strings.

So in other words I need the return to be [New York, USA ; NYC ; NYC, USA ] as opposed to [New York, USA, NYC, NYC, USA]

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?placeOfBirthLabel ?placeOfBirthAltLabel 
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q10833314.
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}

LIMIT 100
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you query explicitly for `skos:altLabel`, you could define the separator when you use `group by ?item ?placeOfBirth` + `group_concat`

Comment: Comma is [hardcoded](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/WDQR/browse/master/blazegraph/src/main/java/org/wikidata/query/rdf/blazegraph/label/LabelService.java$567), use `GROUP_CONCAT`, as AKSW has pointed out.

Comment: Thanks both.  Do you mean a query like this: SELECT ?item ?itemLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(?placeOfBirthAltLabel; separator = "; ") AS ?placeOfBirthAlt)
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q10833314.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth .
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". 
    ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel . 
    ?placeOfBirth skos:altLabel ?placeOfBirthAltLabel .
  }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
LIMIT 500

Comment: Unfortunately couldn't work out how to parse it using group_concat either. Apologies a bit new to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to parse alternative labels. Their values are concatenated by the label service. Just do not use the label service for alternative labels:

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?placeLabel ?place_alt_label WHERE { 
    ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q10833314. 
    OPTIONAL { 
        ?item wdt:P19 ?place .
        OPTIONAL {
            ?place skos:altLabel ?place_alt_label .
            FILTER (lang(?place_alt_label)='en')
            }
    }  
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FplaceLabel%20%3Fplace_alt_label%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ10833314.%20%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP19%20%3Fplace%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3Fplace_alt_label%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fplace_alt_label%29%3D%27en%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D)

If you still want to parse... The comma is [hardcoded](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/WDQR/browse/master/blazegraph/src/main/java/org/wikidata/query/rdf/blazegraph/label/LabelService.java%24567), use grouping and `GROUP_CONCAT` with custom separator instead:

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?placeLabel
    (GROUP_CONCAT(?place_alt_label; separator='; ') AS ?4) WHERE { 
    ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q10833314. 
    OPTIONAL { 
        ?item wdt:P19 ?place .
        OPTIONAL {
            ?place skos:altLabel ?place_alt_label .
            FILTER (lang(?place_alt_label)='en')
            }
    }  
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?placeLabel
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FplaceLabel%0A%20%20%20%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28%3Fplace_alt_label%3B%20separator%3D%27%3B%20%27%29%20as%20%3F4%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ10833314.%20%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP19%20%3Fplace%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3Fplace_alt_label%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fplace_alt_label%29%3D%27en%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FplaceLabel)

---

Be carefull with variables projected by the label service. For example,

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?placeLabel   {...}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?placeLabel
```

should work, whereas

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel (SAMPLE(?placeLabel) AS ?3)   {...}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

shouldn't.

Comment: I'm always surprised how slow some queries are given that there are just 8778 tennis players...

Comment: This should be faster without `OPTIONAL`s, without the label service, and with some query hints...