# Ambiguous 'alt labels' delimeter

Tags: sparql, wikidata

What I want to get is the labels including alt labels.
Some of the strings has comma, which is used as a delimeter as well, 
So I'd like to find out how to get all the individual items properly.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?e ?eLabel ?eAltLabel ?eDescription 
    WHERE {
    { ?e rdfs:label "Apple"@en }
    UNION
    { ?e skos:altLabel "Apple"@en }

    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ko,en". }.
    }
```

The first result of the query is Apple (computer), and shows us eAltLabel like below.

```
Apple, Apple Computer, Apple Computer Inc, Apple Computer, Inc.
```

After getting the result, I split this string using , as a delimeter.

```
Apple
Apple Computer
Apple Computer Inc
Apple Computer
Inc.
```

which is different from what I expected. This is because I consider `,` on the right after `Apple computer` as delimeter. I want to get the last one like `Apple Computer, Inc.`, the full phrase.

How can I disambiguate each label respectively when the labels entail `,` inside? How can I change the sparql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing returns from AltLabel in a SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520591/parsing-returns-from-altlabel-in-a-sparql-query)